# Simplify a ComplexExpand with assumptions gives wrong output

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex, assumptions

Let us define the real and imaginary parts of a specific polynomial root as follows

```
root = Solve[M - LC^2 M x - EI x^2 + EI LC^2 A x^3 == 0, x] // 
  FullSimplify
root1=Assuming[LC > 0 && M > 0 && 0 < A < 1 && EI > 0, 
 Simplify[root[[1, 1, 2]]]]
ReIm1 = Assuming[LC > 0 && M > 0 && 0 < A < 1 && EI > 0, 
   ComplexExpand[ReIm[root1]]];
```

When I simplify this expression

```
R1 = Assuming[LC > 0 && M > 0 && 0 < A < 1 && EI > 0, Simplify[ReIm1[[1]]]]
```

and I ask Mathematica if under my assumptions this quantity is positive I obtain "False" as a response:

```
In:= Reduce[R1>0 && LC>0 && M>0 && 0<A<1 && EI>0, Reals]
Out:= False
```

even though numerically I retrieve that this quantity is positive for a wide range of parameter values (and we actually expect it to be positive always). On the other hand, with the simplifications it correctly captures that the imaginary part is 0 (confirmed numerically). I'm afraid Mathematica is doing something funny with simplifications despite imposing the above assumptions, since when I use FullSimplify instead of Simplify I actually get terms where the imaginary constant appears:

```
In:= Assuming[LC>0 && M>0 && 0<A<1 && EI>0, FullSimplify[ReIm1[[1]]]]
Out:= (1/(3 EI LC^2 A))(EI+Sqrt[EI (EI+3 LC^4 M A)] (Cos[1/3 Arg[EI^3+9/2 EI^2 LC^4 M (1-3 A) A+3/2 I Sqrt[3] LC^2 A Sqrt[EI^3 M (4 EI^2+4 LC^8 M^2 A+EI LC^4 M (1+9 (2-3 A) A))]]]+Cos[1/3 Arg[2 EI^3+9 EI^2 LC^4 M (1-3 A) A+3 I Sqrt[3] LC^2 A] Sqrt[EI^3 M (4 EI^2+4 LC^8 M^2 A+EI LC^4 M (1+9 (2-3 A) A))]]]))
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: I doubt that the Reduce algorithm is able to describe the multidimensional domain of reality or positivity of a trigonemetric function. The "False" is simply an indication that it is easy to find a counterexample or that Reduce finds no way to connect two logical expressions.